# get html source and clear some data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to get source code from a html using PHP OR JS/JQuery, and then I want to comment out specified lines of code in this html file, Jquery has html() which would replace the whole page, but how to delete some lines of source code. Do i need to use PHP to parse the file?

Eg.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html 
 <html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var adData = a JASON object.
   var usersDomain = a url
  </script>
 <head>
 </html>
```

I want to remove the whole script containing var adData, usersDomain. I am not front end developer, trying to figure out this for fun... Any advises are welcome.

Comment: You could potentially use PHP to find the `adData` and delete it. Please provide which website you are wanting to do this with.

Comment: @DaveChen   , I am trying to manipulate wix dot com pages, to remove its ads.

Comment: removing script code of `adData` will not help because on page load it saves in the history of page u need to unregister the  `adData` script

Comment: So like a browser plugin? There's a lot out there you know.

Comment: @DaveChen, I would setup a website, this website loads wix page, also remove its ads. And I could edit my pages at wix, no need to worry about ads at all.

Comment: @dianuj any hints about un-register a script?

Comment: You could have javascript remove the ads afterward. Usually the ad will have a class like `.ad` use your browser tools to find the class names and then with jQuery you can do: `(function($) { $('.ad').remove() })(jQuery);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, source code is rendered by the browser,You have to delete those lines before you are sending to the client(PHP). you will not be able to hide the source code using jquery.

Comment: If you could inject javascript, you could set `adData` to `undefined`.